# How to replace values in an array by values from onother array linked by a common timestamp in both arrays

Tags: php, arrays, replace

I have two identical PHP arrays with two values (Timestamp and Value) per row
for example

```
$A1[1]['timestamp'] = 11:20
$A1[1]['Value'] = 100
$A1[2]['timestamp'] = 11:21
$A1[2]['Value'] = 110

$A2[1]['timestamp'] = 11:20
$A2[1]['Value'] = 85
```

All timestamps in A2 do exist in A1

I want to replace all values in A1 with the value from A2 having an identical timestamp.

So after the merge/replace the new array (or A1) will be

```
$A1[1]['timestamp'] = 11:20
$A1[1]['Value'] = 85
$A1[2]['timestamp'] = 11:21
$A1[2]['Value'] = 110
```

I looked at various array merge/replace options but couldn't find an example in which the replacement was based on a mutual value in one of the fields

Comment: and what you have tried so far to overcome your problem?? Please add your code-effort in your question

Comment: @user12148097 Welcome! Can you show us what you've tried, the results you got and what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this custom loop.

```
foreach($A1 as $k=>$v){
  foreach($A2 as $key=>$val){
    if($A2[$key]['timestamp'] == $A1[$k]['timestamp']){
      $A1[$k]['value'] = $A2[$key]['value'];
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was wondering if there was some smart function, but this will do the job just fine!